# Installing pip packages to $HOME folder

Tags: python, pip

Is it possible? When installing [`pip`](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html), install the python packages inside my `$HOME` folder. (for example, I want to install `mercurial`, using `pip`, but inside `$HOME` instead of `/usr/local`)

I'm with a mac machine and just thought about this possibility, instead of "polluting" my `/usr/local`, I would use my `$HOME` instead.

[PEP370](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/) is exactly about this. Is just creating a `˜/.local` and do a `pip install package` enough to make these packages to be installed only at my $HOME folder?

Comment: Have you checked out virtualenv? You could install packages with pip in an isolated environment.

Comment: I thought about it, but I would like to install some python applications using the existing python (2.6.1), but instead of installing at /usr/local/, install at my $HOME folder and add it to $PATH. I want to know if it's possible, and any caveats of this approach.

Comment: +1 for promoting PEP370.  This is a simple but useful option that more people should know about.

Comment: I was fighting with similar problem (possibly caused by misconfigured pip and easy_install for two different pyhtons). As last resort, I tried to use plain ```$ python setup.py --user install```. And it worked. Package is now installed at home subdir and all works as expected. Will have to talk to my server admin.

Comment: If you need to install PIP, just do something like `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` followed by `python get-pip.py` and you're good to go. Might be useful if you're on a machine where the installed PIP is too old (was the case for me). See http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html for more info.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky for me, with python 3.5, that didn't work. It was: `python setup.py install --user`

Comment: May I know how to do the same for conda install. As ````conda install --user -c conda-forge gdal```` doesn't work.

Answer (score 476, accepted):

While you can use a `virtualenv`, you don't need to.  The trick is passing the PEP370 `--user` argument to the `setup.py` script.  With the latest version of `pip`, one way to do it is:

```
pip install --user mercurial
```

This should result in the `hg` script being installed in `$HOME/.local/bin/hg` and the rest of the hg package in `$HOME/.local/lib/pythonx.y/site-packages/`.

Note, that the above is true for Python 2.6.  There has been a [bit of controversy](http://bugs.python.org/issue7175) among the Python core developers about what is the appropriate directory location on Mac OS X for PEP370-style `user` installations.  In Python 2.7 and 3.2, the location on Mac OS X was changed from `$HOME/.local` to `$HOME/Library/Python`.  This might change in a future release.  But, for now, on 2.7 (and 3.2, if `hg` were supported on Python 3), the above locations will be `$HOME/Library/Python/x.y/bin/hg` and `$HOME/Library/Python/x.y/lib/python/site-packages`.

Comment: Good point.  Unfortunately, there is a bug in Python 2.7 that causes PYTHONUSERBASE to be ignored for OS X framework builds.  It'll be fixed for Python 2.7.3.

Comment: This looks very insteresting. `easy_install` comes installed in Mac OS X by default, so I would have only pip installed outside the `$HOME` folder.

Comment: The `easy_install` that comes with my Snow Leopard installs `pip` on `/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.6.egg`. Doing `which pip` shows `/usr/local/bin/pip`. Installing mercurial with `--user` argument and pip, `which hg` now shows `$HOME/.local/bin/hg`!. (I needed to add `$HOME/.local/bin` to `$PATH` to make it work though.)

Comment: I have tried to change the PYTHONUSERBASE to another location.  No success.  How is this done on Windows specifically?

Comment: Beware, that if you do this and then try to use conda environments the files installed in `.local` will always be hit first which can lead to very hard to track down import errors.

Comment: Note that on OSX, the user site directory's bin folder is not on PATH.  This means scripts installed by packages in the user site directory will not be executable unless you `export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Python/X.Y/bin/`.

Comment: For anyone wondering, on Windows this installs scripts to %APPDATA%\Python\Python36\Scripts

Comment: Also useful when the package you want to install locally is virtualenv.

Comment: `$ echo $(python -c "import site; print(site.USER_BASE)")/bin
/Users/systemdisc/Library/Python/2.7/bin`

Comment: @NedDeily May I know how to do the same for conda install. As ````conda install --user -c conda-forge gdal```` doesn't work.

Comment: You can also get the path of local packages via `python -m site --user-site`

Answer (score 22):

You can specify the `-t` option (`--target`) to specify the destination directory. See `pip install --help` for detailed information. This is the command you need:

```
pip install -t path_to_your_home package-name
```

for example, for installing say mxnet, in my `$HOME` directory, I type:

```
pip install -t /home/foivos/ mxnet
```

Comment: Getting an error `distutils.errors.DistutilsOptionError: can't combine user with prefix, exec_prefix/home, or install_(plat)base`. What does it mean?

Comment: Check https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3826 for a related discussion. I don't know anything more on this, but I never encountered a problem in my environments.

Comment: I would rather give "-t /home/foivos/python_packages" as example, as installing directly into the home directory could lead to a big bunch of files "polluting" the $HOME

Answer (score 21):

I would use virtualenv at your HOME directory.

```
$ sudo easy_install -U virtualenv
$ cd ~
$ virtualenv .
$ bin/pip ...
```

You could then also alter `~/.(login|profile|bash_profile)`, whichever is right for your shell to add ~/bin to your PATH and then that `pip|python|easy_install` would be the one used by default.

Comment: The *"de facto"* way to do this is `virtualenv venv`, `source venv/bin/activate`. You might not necessarily want to **always** use your virtualenv, and by using this method, your prompt is prefixed with `(venv)` when you're using it.

Comment: @nyuszika7h We know how to use virtualenv. But this really answers the question and is a very neat solution.

Comment: @itsafire Who is "we"? I recommend you to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word

Comment: Anyway, I disagree, this is not a "neat solution". It's a pointless hack.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer to your two questions grabbed from the other answers

#### One

Yes

it is possible installing pip packages to **$HOME** instead of **/usr/local/lib/**, but

#### Two

```
mkdir ˜/.local # then
pip install package
```

**is not enough.**

You need

```
pip install package --user
```

and the packages get installed to

```
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.x/site-packages
```

#### Exception when you do not need `--user`

- if you are **not root user**
- On `Debian` together with `Wsl` - Windows Subsystem Linux **no notice**
- On Ubuntu 20.04 **notice** `default to user installation because normal site-packages not writeable` - default config is `/usr/lib` not writeable for other users except root