# error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support': Permission denied

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, virtualenv, pip

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and I am trying to pip install virtualenv but suddenly I got this error.

```
samuel@sampc:~$ pip install virtualenv
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
  Running setup.py egg_info for package virtualenv

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_templates'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
  Running setup.py install for virtualenv
    error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support': Permission denied
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/samuel/build/virtualenv/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-Z2v_fR-record/install-record.txt:
    running install

running build

running build_py

running install_lib

creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support

error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support': Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/samuel/build/virtualenv/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-Z2v_fR-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /home/samuel/.pip/pip.log
```

Does anyone have an idea about my case?

Comment: I just had a similar problem because of wrong permissions for my home folder (some things were not owned by me). While sudo pip install would work, it is be better to fix the permissions instead.

Comment: @VelizarHristov *'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support': Permission denied* clearly states the path and this path has nothing to do with any home folder so no, your problem is not similar to this one in spite of the same type of error in both cases.

Comment: I had similar problem when I try to intall numpy in Python3.  Then 'sudo pip3 install numpy' worked.

Answer (score 115):

I've heard that using `sudo` with `pip` is unsafe.

Try adding `--user` to the end of your command, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143496).

```
pip install packageName --user
```

I suspect that installing with this method means the packages are not available to other users.

Comment: 2nd not using sudo with pip, where possible.  The user flag worked for me.  If this worked for the OP, could you please mark it as answered?

Comment: this didn't work for me, saw the following error:
`error: can't combine user with prefix, exec_prefix/home, or install_(plat)base`

Comment: Are you using an additional arguments to `pip`? Like `--prefix /foo/bar`?

Answer (score 55):

You don't have permission to the Python folder.

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/python2.7
```

Comment: More importantly It's the right way. Installing with sudo has security issues!

Comment: Is this really a good idea?  What about other users on the system (in a shared environment)?  I suppose its a get over the hump to keep pushing foward

Comment: Its Worked.  Thanks

Comment: Its Worked. Thanks

Comment: Something what I should lern

Answer (score 16):

Use

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

Apparently you will have powers of administrator when adding "sudo" before the line... just don't forget your password.

Comment: Is installing py libraries as root safe?

Comment: Never ever run `sudo pip…`. See [What are the risks of running 'sudo pip'?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21055859/95735)

Comment: Nope nope nope nope nope nope nope nope nope - I hope you aren't a sysadmin

Answer (score 3):

use

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

You have a permission denied error. This states your current user does not have the root permissions.So run the command as a super user.

Comment: Never ever run `sudo pip…`. See [What are the risks of running 'sudo pip'?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21055859/95735)

Answer (score 2):

In the case of permission denied error, you just need to go with this command.

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

**sudo** before the command will throw away the current user permissions error.

**Note:** For security risks, You should read piotr comment.

Comment: Never ever run `sudo pip…`. See [What are the risks of running 'sudo pip'?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21055859/95735)

Answer (score 2):

It's because the virtual environment viarable has not been installed.

Try this:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
virtualenv --python python3 env
source env/bin/activate
pip install <Package>
```

or

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv --python python3 env
source env/bin/activate
pip3 install <Package>
```

Answer (score 2):

pip is not give permission so can't do pip install.Try below command.

```
apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

Answer (score 2):

First, `sudo pip install 'package-name'` means nothing it will return

```
sudo: pip: command not found
```

You get the Permission denied, you shouldn't use pip install as root anyway. You can just install the packages into your own user like mentionned above with

```
pip install 'package-name' --user
```

and it will work as you intend. If you need it in any other user just run the same command and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change permission on the mentioned path.

Comment: Not a good idea to change permission giving access to a user you should consider to install it globally