# Structure Python application with client and server parts

Tags: python, directory-structure

I have an application that is currently in the following folder structure:

```
myapp/
  client/
  core/
  server/
  template_files/
```

It has a server side and a client side component and when I deploy the code to a user, I don't want to include the server side code as well.  Both `client` and `server` need the `core` code to run.

Reading about general Python project structure, I realise I should start by changing my structure to:

```
myapp/
  myapp/
    client/
    core/
    server/
      template_files/ (template is only needed by the server)
  bin/
  setup.py
```

What's the best way to structure my directories and do code deployment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to have three separate packages instead of one, even your second structure will result in a package (python egg) that contains all the sub-modules which will result in the server code being packaged with the client code.

What you want is to split them up into three individual packages (i.e. `myapp.client`, `myapp.core` and `myapp.server`) and they will have separated directory structures, so in effect you would have something like

```
myapp.client/
  myapp/
    client/
  setup.py
myapp.core/
  myapp/
    core/
  setup.py
myapp.server/
  myapp/
    server/
      template_files/
  setup.py
```

As they will all become proper python packages, you can define dependencies in the `setup.py` for `myapp.client` and `myapp.server` to require `myapp.core`, so if/when you deploy the packages onto pypi (or others) your users can simply do `pip install myapp.client` to get the client library installed onto their system with all dependencies fetched.

You don't necessarily have to have a `bin` in anywhere.  You can take advantage of the [`entry_points`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) attribute in the `setup` function to let setuptools create the "binary" for you in an OS agnostic manner.  Just define the main function(s) inside your library and let setuptools create the executable for you for your users.

Lastly, you might want to take a look at what other open source projects have done for packaging their libraries, here are some examples:

- [Flask](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask)
- [Jinja2](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2)
- [plone.app.discussion](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.discussion)

Comment: Did what you suggested is called [implicit namespace packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) (BTW: in which directories do I need to create `__init__.py`?)? If not: how would you refer (import) modules from `myapp.core` package from modules residing withing `myapp.server` package? Do I have to create [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) to make it work?

Comment: @patryk.beza yes you have to install the package into some environment, virtual environment is the usual recommendation because it offers some form of isolation from the rest of the system.  One other option is to do so at the [user level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143077/how-can-i-install-packages-in-my-home-folder-with-pip), or the least recommended, as root at the system level.