# Importing modules with same name

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools, setup.py

Basically, I have two python projects, one is located under `myapp/screening` and the other `myapp/server`. I'm currently developing the `server` module and want to import functions from `screening` using `myapp.screening`.

My folder structure is as shown bellow:

```
myapp/
    screening/
        screening-env/
        myapp/
            __init__.py
            screening/
                __init__.py
                screening_task.py
                submodule1/
                    # __init__.py and ub module files
                submodule2/
                    # __init__.py and sub module files
                submodule3/
                    # __init__.py and sub module files
        tests/
            # __init__.py and test scripts
        setup.py
    server/
        server-env/
        myapp/
            __init__.py
            server/
                __init__.py
                server_task.py
        tests/
            __init__.py
            server_test.py
```

I structured my project following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955165/structure-python-application-with-client-and-server-parts).

My `setup.py` is basically as bellow:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='myapp-screening',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=[
        'myapp.screening',
        'myapp.screening.submodule1',
        'myapp.screening.submodule2',
        'myapp.screening.submodule3'
    ],
)
```

I activated my `server-env` and installed the screening project by navigating to `myapp/screening/` (same directory as `setup.py`) and ran `python setup.py develop`.

Finally, both `server_test.py` and `server_task` are such as bellow:

```
from myapp.screening.screening_test import foo

foo()
```

When I run `python -m myapp.server.server_task` or `python -m test.server_test` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp.screening'
```

This error makes sense if I'm running `python -m myapp.server.server_task` because local `myapp` existis and **might** be overwriting the installed `myapp` that contains the `screening` modules.

Is there a way to import stuff from `screening` using `from myapp.screening.screening_task import foo`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some more research I found [this similar (in a way) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936884/python-import-path-packages-with-the-same-name-in-different-folders) that leads to [import python modules with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630394/import-python-modules-with-the-same-name) and [How do I create a namespace package in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675734/how-do-i-create-a-namespace-package-in-python).

The answer for "importing modules with same name" is not useful since it says to rename one module or turn the project directory into a package.

The other question is exactly what I want. It basically talks about the [`pkgutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html) with which you can 'append' modules to a given namespace.

I understand and share some opinions against this technique for some cases (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936884/python-import-path-packages-with-the-same-name-in-different-folders)) but since it's presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955165/structure-python-application-with-client-and-server-parts) sometimes you want separated structures so you don't patch everything togheter even when you don't want everything