# What is the purpose of $HOME/.local

Tags: python, pip

I've noticed that I have `$HOME/.local` on my machine and seems that this directory contains mostly stuff related to python, [here](http://termbin.com/vw35) is it's full list (it is a bit long).

I would like to ask which action created this directory? I suppose it was `pip install --user -r requirements.txt` (bellow are commands by which I've figured it out) but I am wondering if there any other tools that stores data here? I suppose if it was `pip` so `easy_install` can do this as well or not? Are there any other tools you're aware of that uses this directory or it is `pip` exclusively?

Following command shows that some python module was imported from this directory, output of last one is [here](http://termbin.com/xs62) (it is a bit long):

```
marek@ubuntu:~$ python -c 'import mock; print mock.__file__'
/home/marek/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.pyc
marek@ubuntu:~$ echo $PYTHONPATH

marek@ubuntu:~$ tree .local/ | grep  mock
│           ├── mock-1.0.1.egg-info
│           ├── mock.py
│           ├── mock.pyc
│           │   ├── mock.py
│           │   ├── mock.pyc
marek@ubuntu:~$ pip show -f mock
---
Name: mock
Version: 1.0.1
Location: /home/marek/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: 
Files:
Cannot locate installed-files.txt
marek@ubuntu:~$ python -c 'import sys, pprint; pprint.pprint(sys.path)'
['',
 '/home/marek/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nupic-0.3.0.dev0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/marek/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
marek@ubuntu:~$ python -v 2>&1 | tee modules
```

The [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143077/how-can-i-install-packages-in-my-home-folder-with-pip) answer says that there should be `$HOME/.local/bin/hg` in this directory if it was created with `pip` but I do not have this file. So was it created with `pip` or not?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It is not directly connected to Python, but Pip uses it. Let's start from the beginning. First you should understand, what the [`/usr`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html) directory is used for:

> In current Unices, /usr is where user-land programs and data (as opposed to 'system land' programs and data) are.

It should be used for data installed by the system, i.e. official packages of the distribution.

The `/usr/local` directory mirrors the structure of the `/usr` directory, but can be used by system administrators to install local or third party packages for all users.

The `~/.local` directory now has the same purpose just for a single user.

Usually you'll install your packages with the default package manager using the `/usr` directory. But since you're using Pip as package manager for your Python modules, these are installed in `~/.local`.

So basically `pip` might have created `~/.local` or just any other programm writing data to one of the directories located there. `~/.local/share` for example is used by most applications to store their data.

Comment: The environment variable `PYTHONUSERBASE` can be used to change it from `$HOME/.local`

Answer (score 34):

$HOME/.local is where user applications place their files and folders in the user's home directory.

According to the [Home Directory](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html#Home%20Directory) section of the [file-hierarchy(7)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html) man-page, user-specific data should be split among the following sub-directories within `$HOME/.local`:

- `~/.local/bin` for executables that shall appear in the user's $PATH search path.
  In Python's case this might be a tool like `pipenv`.
- `~/.local/lib` for static, private vendor data that is compatible with all architectures.
  In Python's case these are libraries like `requests`.
- `~/.local/share` for resources shared between multiple packages.
  In Python's case this might be the `virtualenvs`. It is also part of the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) where it is mentioned as the default value of `$XDG_DATA_HOME`.

From the above observations it should become clear that `$HOME/.local` has nothing in particular to do with Python itself. `pip install --user` putting its files into `$HOME/.local` simply means it is compliant with the recommendations published by [freedesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org).

If you install packages with `sudo pip install`, it will distribute the package files according to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html) into the [`/usr`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html#theUsrHierarchy) hierarchy instead, which follows the same logic at system-level, just as your distribution's package manager does.

Comment: It’s good to know that .local is specified in linux man hier. It’s worth noting that it is NOT specified in BSD’s man hier.

Comment: It's not in linux's "man hier" either. The file-hierarchy(7) man-page is packaged with systemd by the guys around freedesktop.org.