# How can I make pip packages only locally available after installing them with sudo?

Tags: python, pip

I've installed a couple of pip packages as sudo. As a result pip requires me to enter my password when upgrading or removing installed packages. Is there a simple way to move all packages to the local site, such that I don't need to bother about sudo anymore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install packages in my $HOME folder with pip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143077/how-can-i-install-packages-in-my-home-folder-with-pip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "local site", however I assume you mean [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

You can use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to get a list of all installed packages, and then use `sudo pip uninstall -r requirements.txt` to remove all the packages from the system directory. Then setup and activate your virtualenv, and `pip install -r requirements.txt` to get them all installed in your virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install --user package_name
```

Should also work with `setup.py` files.

```
python setup.py --user install
```

And, just in case you want it, within a script.

```
import pip
pip.main(["install", "--user", "package_name"])
```