# Error while upgrading pip

Tags: python-3.x

> > > pip3 install --upgrade pip
> > >       Syntax Error: invalid syntax

I am using python3.3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894511/upgrade-pip-error-message

Comment: PIP should be run from the command line.
After the installation, the upgrades can be done. Donot use the command in the interpreter.