# How to install packages on networked computer

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, ipython

I'm using an Ipython2.7 notebook to run some code. Recently discovered that all my data was corrupted and I need to do it all again (meaning I am very very behind schedule) I figured I could half the time required if I could run it on a second computer. So I've gone into a uni computer cluster where the computers have python 2.7 installed. I can open the notebook, but it won't run as the first line is

```
import mlpy.wavelet
```

And it gives me an import error. I've tried downloading and installing it from sourceforge, but it seems to install it to the a Q drive, which I don't have access to. I am completely lost on what to do here, I can't even remember how I first installed it on my laptop. I have a feeling I pip installed it but I have no clue how to do this on a uni comp.

Any rapid responses would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use pip to install packages in your user's home directory. 
Run `pip install --user mply` to install mply and your other dependencies.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143496/489345) for reference.

Comment: Do you mean in the command prompt? That says that pip is not reconized etc

Comment: You can also install pip locally with a `--user` flag. See [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

Comment: I don't understand where to type this in, I've tried doing it through the conda command line that's on here but pip isn't updated. When I tried to update it I got a blue screen..