# What should be my python packages path for a user install on MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, pip, package, pythonpath

I'm on Mac OS X and I've heard that to avoid global installation of packages (using sudo) that might cause problems with the python files that OS X uses, the path to install python packages must be different than that of OS X.

Currently python executables are installed in :

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

Pip installs modules over here :

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Python is used from here :

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Are these paths safe?

Comment: You are looking for user installs. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143077/how-can-i-install-packages-in-my-home-folder-with-pip

Answer (score 6):

If you are on OS X, you should also have Python in `/usr/bin`:

```
$ which -a python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

If you are using `brew`, the first `python` should be a symlink:

```
$ ls -hl $(which python)
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin    34B Jun 23 16:53 /usr/local/bin/python -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.11/bin/python
```

If you are not using `brew`, you will have to explain to us how you installed a second version of `python`.

You should also have at least two `site-packages`:

```
$ find /usr -name 'site-packages'
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

If you installed `python` using `brew`, you should also have `pip`:

```
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

You should probably upgrade that to the latest `pip`:

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
```

It should be safe to install `python` packages using `/usr/local/bin/pip` because they will be installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. The `/usr/local` path is specifically for [local software](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY). Also, `brew` installs its files to `/usr/local`, so if you are using `brew`, you are already installing files there.

I am not sure why some folks say not to install any packages globally. I have never seen a reference that explained why this was a bad idea. If multiple users need the same package, it makes more sense to install it globally.

When I first started using `virtualenv`, it did not always work the way I expected it to. I had a machine with multiple users that needed `requests`, and because of problems with `virtualenv`, I wound up installing it globally using `pip`.

Both `virtualenv` and `pip` have improved a lot since I first started using them and I can see how using them can prevent some problems. If you are developing new software that needs the latest version of a package, `virtualenv` allows you to install the package without affecting the rest of the system. However, I still do not see why it is a bad idea to install packages globally.

Comment: Here are a couple reasons not to sudo pip: [security](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42021993/717274) and dependencies - when different parent packages need different versions of the same dependent package.  If one parent updates the global dependent package, it potentially breaks the other parent.

Comment: If `pip` is installed via `brew` then `sudo` is not necessary.

Comment: Gotcha.  So you are referring to your own local user's global installs, right?  For which you are free to share installs across projects.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make use of virtual environments, you can learn more about them here: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

to sum up

1. Create a virtual environment (venv): `$ virtualenv venv`

> This creates a copy of Python in whichever directory you ran the command in placing it in a folder named venv.

2. Activate the virtual environment: `$ source venv/bin/activate`
3. Install packages with pip: `$ pip install requests`
4. When you are done deactivate the virtual environment: `$ deactivate`

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options you can take, the easiest (as others have suggested) is `virtualenv`. Hopefully that's already installed if not, this is one of the few modules you should install globally. If you have Python 3.4+, you "should" have `venv` module (which is similar to virtualenv, but it's maintained by the Python team).

*python2*

```
virtualenv ~/.py-venvs/python2
```

*python3*

```
python3 -m venv ~/.py-venvs/python3
```

You could install modules to the local user using `pip`, but I'm not sure how well this is supported these days though:

```
pip install --user requests
```

You could also append directories to the `$PYTHONPATH` bash variable, but this should only be done as a last resort and under parental supervision :D. Try the other methods before this one.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using virtualenv now and it is perfect for my use.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't be mucking about with Python package paths, and you shouldn't be installing Python packages globally at all. Use a virtualenv for each project, and let pip install the libraries locally inside the virtualenv.

Comment: What about tools like `awscli`?