# 'sudo pip install -e .' updates easy-install.pth under /usr/local/lib, python can't import

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip, easy-install

I'm on MacOs Sierra.

I'm having an issue where installing my own package with `sudo pip install -e` results in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth` being updated to point to the package but apparently not found when python starts up.

This smells like it's related to my having linked `/usr/local/bin/python` to  `/usr/bin/python` some time back to address some other version conflict type issue that I can no longer recall.

Is there a sensible way to address this by editing something in, say, `site.py`?

---

I'm not sure what additional specifics might be needed here. Here's a plethora of related command output from the system.

The pip install seems to succeed:

```
~$ cd workspace/mypackage
mypackage$ sudo -H pip install -e .

Obtaining file:///Users/me/workspace/mypackage

     ...[snip]...

  Running setup.py develop for mypackage
Successfully installed boto3-1.4.4 botocore-1.5.46 mypackage docutils-0.13.1 functools32-3.2.3.post2 futures-3.1.1 jmespath-0.9.2 jsonschema-2.6.0 python-dateutil-2.6.0 s3transfer-0.1.10

mypackage$ cd /tmp
tmp$ python -c 'import mypackage'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mypackage
```

Here's how the python versions look. Again, the link to `/usr/bin/python` (and moving the original `/usr/local/bin/python` to `-cellar`) was a workaround for another (MacOs python specific, IIRC?) issue I was having previously.

```
tmp$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python

tmp$ ls -l $(which python)
lrwxr-xr-x  1 me  admin  15 Apr 24 11:59 /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python

tmp$ ls /usr/local/bin/python2.7*
python2.7                python2.7-cellar         python2.7-config         python2.7-config-cellar

tmp$ /usr/local/bin/python2.7-cellar --version
Python 2.7.13

tmp$ /usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

The `-cellar`-ed version of python does find the install:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python2.7-cellar  -c 'import mypackage; print mypackage.__file__'
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mypackage/__init__.pyc
```

The `easy-install.pth` that was updated by the install is in `/usr/local/lib`.

```
tmp$ sudo find /usr -name easy-install.pth
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth

tmp$ cat /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth
/Users/me/workspace/mypackage
```

Some `pip` details:

```
tmp$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

tmp$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

ls -l /usr/local/bin/pip
lrwxr-xr-x  1 me  admin  31 Apr 22 21:27 /usr/local/bin/pip -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/pip

tmp$ sudo find /usr -name pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.3.0.0/libexec/bin/pip
/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.3.0.0/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/pip
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/libexec/pip
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/libexec/pip/build/lib/pip
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/libexec/pip/pip
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip

tmp$ ls -ld /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip
drwxr-xr-x  34 me  admin  1156 Apr 22 21:27 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip
```

No corresponding site-packages with pip or easy-install.pth under /usr/lib/python2.7:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/lib/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  75 Oct 21  2016 /usr/lib/python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7

tmp$ ls /usr/lib/python2.7/site*
/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py  /usr/lib/python2.7/site.pyc /usr/lib/python2.7/site.pyo
```

My `sys.path`:

```
tmp$ python -c 'import sys; print "\n".join(sys.path)'

/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python
/usr/local/lib/python2.7
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/lib/python27.zip
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
```

Alles Normal in a virtualenv:

```
mypackage$ mkvirtualenv testpip
    ...[snip]...
(testpip) mypackage$ sudo -H pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///Users/me/workspace/mypackage
Installing collected packages: mypackage
  Running setup.py develop for mypackage
Successfully installed mypackage

(testpip) mypackage$ ls ~/.virtualenvs/testpip/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mypackage.egg-link
/Users/me/.virtualenvs/testpip/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mypackage.egg-link

(testpip) mypackage$ cd /tmp
(testpip) tmp$ python -c 'import mypackage; print mypackage.__file__'
/Users/me/workspace/mypackage/mypackage/__init__.pyc
```

...or when doing a noneditable install:

```
mypackage$ sudo -H pip install .
Processing /Users/me/workspace/mypackage
Installing collected packages: mypackage
  Running setup.py install for mypackage ... done
Successfully installed mypackage-1.0.0

mypackage$ cd /tmp
tmp$ python -c 'import mypackage; print mypackage.__file__'
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mypackage/__init__.pyc
```

Comment: In your last example the output reads `Successfully installed argus-tools-1.0.0`. But wasn't it `mypackage` that you want to install? Also everything fine in a virtualenv so why not stick to that solution? You probably should have used a virtualenv in the very beginning before messing around with symlinks to other python versions.

Comment: You may want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143077/how-can-i-install-packages-in-my-home-folder-with-pip

Comment: Oops, argus-tools was from the original case, I genericized it after determining that the specific package wasn't the issue and missed that one. Fixed.

Yes, sticking to virtualenv would address the problem, but now that I'm here I'd like to understand what's going on under the hood. :)

Comment: Also, this may end up deployed in settings where virtualenv isn't an option (although those wouldn't be on MacOs so I'm sure this issue wouldn't come up either.)