# Installing numpy, keras and theano without root privileges on linux

Tags: python, linux, pythonpath, site-packages

I have been given access to a University Data Center to deploy an Image Analysis python project. The server has Python 2.7 and 3.5 installed and I can see that it is missing packages like numpy, theano and keras which I have used in my code as additional libraries.

The problem at hand is, that I do not have access to install anything, or run commands like pip install or apt-get install, and cannot copy anything to the original site-packages location in my server.

But I can copy files into my userspace, and I tried to:
- clone numpy and its prerequisites, and all the additional packages I need into a folder called site-packages.
- add this path to my sys.path, but it gives me errors like "cannot import multiarray"

I'm new to Linux, and my question is: can I copy package files into a Linux system and provide this path to my PYTHONPATH to run the code?

Comment: You should take a look of the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143077/how-can-i-install-packages-in-my-home-folder-with-pip

Comment: It should work, but the package pip is missing. That's why I was manually copying the library files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for:

```
pip install --user package_name
```

You might also need to investigate compiling some packages from their source code, but this will depend on the package.

From the [user guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/?highlight=--user) more on pip install --user:

> pip install --user follows four rules:
>
> 1. When globally installed packages are on the python path, and they
>      conflict with the installation requirements, they are ignored, and not
>      uninstalled.
> 2. When globally installed packages are on the python path,
>      and they satisfy the installation requirements, pip does nothing, and
>      reports that requirement is satisfied (similar to how global packages
>      can satisfy requirements when installing packages in a
>      --system-site-packages virtualenv).
> 3. pip will not perform a --user install in a --no-site-packages > virtualenv (i.e. the default kind of
>      virtualenv), due to the user site not being on the python path. The
>      installation would be pointless.
> 4. In a --system-site-packages
>      virtualenv, pip will not install a package that conflicts with a
>      package in the virtualenv site-packages. The --user installation would
>      lack sys.path precedence and be pointless.

Edit: If pip itself is not installed then you can read up here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/