# conda equivalent of pip install --user

Tags: pip, conda

To install to my own directory I can use

```
pip install --user package
```

Alternatively I can use

```
conda install package
```

How do I ask `conda` to install to my home directory since conda does not take a `--user` flag?

[Installing pip packages to $HOME folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143077/installing-pip-packages-to-home-folder)

Answer (score -7, accepted):

According to the documentation:

--use-local

Comment: Using this, I still get `The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.`

Comment: This answer is not correct. The documentation says '--use-local' is "Identical to '-c local'." which means it is using a local channel for the package source, not installing for the local user.

Answer (score 15):

I don't think it's possible. Use virtual environments (`conda create`).

Answer (score 10):

To install conda packages on your own directory you can follow these steps:

1. Create a blank environment

   ```
   conda create -y -n my-conda-env
   ```

   Replace the name `my-conda-env` with any name you want to give the environment.
2. Activate the environment

   ```
   source activate my-conda-env
   ```

   Don't forget to replace `my-conda-env` with the name you gave the conda environment from the previous step
3. Install your package

   ```
   conda install -c bioconda epa-ng
   ```

And that's it, the package should be installed on your own directory

Comment: what if I want to perform conda update: `conda update conda` in my local directory sense? It seems like I can only install packages based on existing conda.

Answer (score 9):

See `-p` option [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html):

```
 -p PATH, --prefix PATH
              Full path to environment prefix.
```

So to install to, say, `local` under your home directory, do:

```
conda install -p $HOME/local packagename
```

Note, however, this is not a "clean" install as it adds a bunch of conda-related files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an exact match for the --user flag, but a reasonable analogue is to use a virtual environment.

What I do when I have to install to a shared CentOS server where I don't have admin access:

First I run

`conda env list`

will list all conda virtual environments and display the path to each.  Once you have the environment created and can see it in the `conda env list`, copy the path to the environment.

If you need to create one, you can do that with `conda create` or by running `anaconda-navigator` and using the GUI.

Activate your environment (if not active) with

`conda activate [environment_name]`

or

`activate [environment_name]`

depending on your system (most linux systems use the first, Windows and CentOS use the latter).

Now you can use

`conda install -p [environment_path] [package_name]`

and you are off to the races.

This is really a work around; it's not the best but it does install the package to the selected virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

The current Anaconda Install Individual Edition, when run in a linux local account, installs in a local directory. So all the subsequent installs should install there, too.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the method mentioned by [Andrey Portnoy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52248671/7482962), you can also [define the default environment path](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-environment-directories-envs-dirs) in the `.condarc` file.

You can check the environment directories `conda` currently uses by checking the key `envs directories` with

```bash
conda info
```

When creating a new named environment, conda will place the environment in the first writable environment in the list.

So, to change my default environment path, I have added the following lines to my `.condarc` file in my `$HOME` directory.

```bash
envs_dirs:
  - /Users/myusername/.conda/envs
  - /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply:

```
sudo conda install -c conda-forge package
```

Or:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ./
conda install -c conda-forge package
```