# use pymongo without installing it

Tags: python, pip, pymongo-3.x

I want to use pymongo in my server code which will run in server machine, But don't have permission to install pip or any libraries as it is a shared machine, then how to access mongodb connection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing pip packages to $HOME folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143077/installing-pip-packages-to-home-folder)

Comment: `pip install --user <your_user> pymongo`

Answer (score -1):

download [pymongo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver) files and run setup.py