# Executing Python module without installing it

Tags: python, pandas, installation

How can we run python scripts implementing pandas module in the environment where pandas is not installed?

For example, on a server we don't have permission to install python modules. We have a script which is using the pandas module, so how can we run those scripts?

Comment: Can't you just install the library with pip ?

Comment: Add more context, Where are you trying to run the script? Are you using Docker?

Comment: @ikibir: I don't have access to install module and use pip within VDI.

Comment: @prp: i'm trying to run the script on unix server on which pandas is not installed. is there any way to run the python scripts by with out installing python modules?

Comment: Most python environment allow 2 groups of additional packages: one is common to all users, but there is another one per user. The key is to intall the required packages with `pip install --user ...`

Answer (score 0):

In short: no, you can't. You have to install the package.

There are at least two options. First, you can [install the packages that are not in the system to your home dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143077/installing-pip-packages-to-home-folder) (but this is messy and dependent on the changes to the OS-level setup). You use:

```
pip install --user pandas
```

However, a better way is to use virtual environment (e.g. `venv`):

```
python -m venv local-env
```

In this way you can create a local copy of Python environment in which you can install `pandas` and any other dependencies of your code. And it is fully under your control.

On `venv` you can read more in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).